# Convert Eclipse Project Using CVS to Use Git

Tags: git, migration, cvs, egit, eclipse-mars

I am using **Eclipse Mars** for a **Java EE** project that currently uses **CVS**. I am in the process of migrating the source code along with its version history to **Git**.

When this is achieved, I want to remove any references to **CVS** from the project and continue with **Git**.

In the **Project Properties** dialog Tree View I can see **CVS** (under **Resources** and **Builder** and above **Deployment Assembly**). I want this **CVS** item to disappear.

In a separate project I work on that uses **Git** I can see a **Git** item in the Tree View of the **Project Properties** dialog. I would like that **Git** item to appear in the aforementioned project as well.

So, basically I want the project that has references to **CVS** to reference **Git** instead.

I don't see any simple way to do this and was wondering if a solution to this problem is available.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your git repo in place just delete all the project in your WS (presuming they're pointing to your CVS location). Then clone your new Git repo and run the 'Import Projects...' from the Team menu to get Git versions of the projects back into your WS.